# Subtract an integer from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, subtraction

I have a variable which is:

```
$sum = 42500;
```

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$targetsarray = array(
    '5000' => '',
    '5000' => '',
    '10000' => '',
    '10000' => '',
    '10000' => '',
    '10000' => '',
    '10000' => '',
    '12000' => '',
    '12000' => '',
    '15000' => '',
    '15000' => '',
    '15000' => '',
};
```

The key inside the $targetsarray is generated dynamically from the database so it in fact looks like this:

```
$targetsarray = array(
    $targets => '',
};
```

What I would like to achieve in the array is to subtract the $sum value by each consecutive key in the array so that the final $targetsarray looks like this:

```
$sum = 45000;

$targetsarray = array(
    '5000' => '40000', // subtract 5000 from 45000
    '5000' => '35000', // subtract 5000 from 40000
    '10000' => '25000', // subtract 10000 from 35000
    '10000' => '15000', // subtract 10000 from 25000
    '10000' => '5000', // subtract 10000 from 15000
    '10000' => '0', 
    '10000' => '0',
    '10000' => '0',
    '10000' => '0',
    '10000' => '0',
    '10000' => '0',
    '10000' => '0',
};
```

Is there anyway that I can subtract the $sum from each key in the $targetsarray? Your help will be highly appreciated from an array noobie :)

Comment: All keys of an array must be unique. You can’t have `5000` twice and `10000` ten times as the keys of an array.

Comment: What @SharanyaDutta said.

Comment: Hi @SharanyaDutta, thank you for your comment. May I ask if there is a better way to do it? The keys in the array represent the monthly target for sales and the value represents the fee accumulated so there is always a possibility of duplicate keys. I've tried lots of solutions so far and none have been effective so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply have two arrays:

```
$targetsarray = array(5000, 5000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000);
$anotherarray = array();
$sum = 45000;
foreach($targetsarray as $val){
$anotherarray[] = $sum = ($sum >= $val) ? $sum-$val : 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow @sharanya thank you so much I really appreciate it! I went back and forward using for & while loops. You make it look easy. Thank you again for your answer, I'll definitely be sure to learn from it :)